# jquery mobile: what is proper way to programatically fire event on a jqm Select Menu

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery

**edit A:** this is NOT a jquery question, but rather a **jquery Mobile** question.

**edit B:** I changed the title ... originally I asked how to fire 'click' event specifically, but apparently the 'click' event is not the proper event to use if you want to re-create a jqm:Select Menu choice.

how to programatically fire an event on a jquery mobile select menu?

```
<select id       = 'my_select'   
        name     = 'my_select'   
        onchange = 'gf_handle_change( this.value );' >
  <option id = 'option_A'  value = 'A'> A </option>
  <option id = 'option_B'  value = 'B'> B </option>
</select>

<script>
  function gf_fire_event( args_val )
    { alert( 'test : ' + jQuery( '#option_' + args_val ) ) ; 
      jQuery( '#option_' + args_val ).trigger( 'click' ) ;
    }
  function gf_handle_change( args_val )
    { alert( args_val )  ;
    }
  gf_fire_event( 'A' ) ;
</script>
```

This does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){       
    $("#test-button").on( "click", function(event, ui) {
      $('#my_select option#option_B').trigger('click');    
    });

    $("#my_select option").each(function(){
        $(this).on( "click", function(event, ui) {
          $(this).attr('selected' , true);
          $('#my_select').selectmenu('refresh');                
        });         
    });    
});
```

Working jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/RZ68b/

One more thing, do not use onclick="... or onchange="... with jQuery Mobile, this could case problems with event triggering. Always bind your event programatically.

Comment: I believe he wants to trigger the event programatically, not bind an event listener.

Comment: @Gajotres, thank you, but I am ok binding events ... it's the triggering that is bothering me.

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/RZ68b/ or do you also want to change selected option?

Comment: interesting ... yes, but no ... it does fire an event on the literal <option>, but it does not affect the Select Menu itself. So when you click your button, and it triggers a option_B event, the Select Menu should be updated. I think the problem is that the .trigger('click') does not go into the jquery mobile framework ... maybe?

Comment: This is it: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/RZ68b/ , click is triggered but you alse need to trigger select box markup enhancement: $('#my_select').selectmenu('refresh');

Comment: interesting ... so in a way it is fair to say that jqm does Not have a built-in mechanism to do this (to fire a jqm-click); so therefore it is necessary to recreate each individual step.

Comment: It has but its own event handling stands in a way, in some cases onclick and onchange wont even work.

Answer (score 1):

That will do it

```
function gf_fire_event( args_val )
{
    //Select an option
    $('#my_select option[value=' + args_val +']').attr("selected", "selected");
    //Refresh jQM select menu
    $('#my_select').selectmenu('refresh');
    //Trigger change event
    $('#my_select').trigger('change');
}
```

See working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmatseykanets/Qhswt/)

Comment: this does work also. I had already been working with Gajotres fiddle script when you submitted yours.

Comment: your's also includes a change-event call.